# Xcode warnings: Not such file or directory (.pcm files)

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I'm working on an iOS project and Xcode is showing me the following warnings:

> warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Foundation-KJNK6ICRXLXW.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Foundation-KJNK6ICRXLXW.pcm
>   note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/UIKit-35ZFG9L90CDZV.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/UIKit-35ZFG9L90CDZV.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/FBSDKCoreKit-2R2UGDO79AKYU.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/FBSDKCoreKit-2R2UGDO79AKYU.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Darwin-2GOAYMLU92JOT.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Darwin-2GOAYMLU92JOT.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Accounts-3S3JQK7N2N5QB.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Accounts-3S3JQK7N2N5QB.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/CoreGraphics-5GV9RND36JIM.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/CoreGraphics-5GV9RND36JIM.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/AudioToolbox-1BW8VLA36OG1L.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/AudioToolbox-1BW8VLA36OG1L.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/QuartzCore-1EU3UYK02HRLW.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/QuartzCore-1EU3UYK02HRLW.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/ObjectiveC-20S1MT415HZXU.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/ObjectiveC-20S1MT415HZXU.pcm
>   warning: /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/CommonCrypto-210H9VRZX42BI.pcm: No such file or directory
>   note: while processing /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/CommonCrypto-210H9VRZX42BI.pcm

**Things I tried:**

- Remove derived data, clean build folder and build again
- Disable Clang Module Debugging
- Deintegrate and install Pods again
- Change debug information format to DWARF with dSYM File
- Remove the files shown in the log e.g. `rm -rf /var/folders/qj/lk4bdr_x5fs9cvcj4jgx61mmy6f8jd/C/org.llvm.clang.codytwinton/ModuleCache/2UNUM8IHHP92Q/Foundation-KJNK6ICRXLXW.pcm`
- Delete ModuleCache: `rm -rf /var/folders/v2/vjx2r5k16tz36wn8v4yn_sth0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.moraleda/ModuleCache`

Any ideas?

Comment: try by Deleting `ModuleCache` folder(located adjascent to DerivedData folder)

Comment: Didn't make a difference. Adding it to the list :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

same here since I added a target to my project to build a "development-version" of my app for testing purposes.

I've been get rid of theses warnings by setting (only for the target I added) the Debug Information Format to "DWARF" instead of "DWARF with dSym" into > Build Settings menu > Build Options.

[image]

Comment: It is worth noting. This would remove the dSym file from the build package, needed to symbolicate. (I'm getting this warning from my primary target.)

Comment: @AndresCanella is right. This method will disable any stack-trace information, when your app will crash accidentally

Answer (score 3):

In `Build Settings` set

```
Generate Debug Symbols = No
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this issue get resolved? I am having the same issue after installing the newest FacebookSDK cocoapods.

The only solution I found

1. Setting the Debug information format for Debug to "DWARF"
2. Setting GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER=NO (this should only be done if making a static library).

Comment: It got resolved cleaning my derived data and reinstalling Xcode. My project data was corrupted and therefore I had no way to get rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst changing Format to "DWARF" instead of "DWARF with dSym" into > Build Settings menu > Build Options, answers the question, it will disable your ability to use a tool (like Firebase) to check the error logs.

A better solution would be on the command line to rebuild the pods:

```
pod deintegrate
pod update
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing **all** derived data of **all** my apps. I used these steps:

1. Open **Locations** tab in the Preferences of Xcode
2. Click on the tiny arrow button at the right side of the **Derived Data** path
3. Delete the **DerivedData** folder in Finder
4. Restart Xcode
5. Rebuild app

Comment: I deleted Derived data folder, closed the XCode, opened it again, cleaned the project and run it again, but the problem is reproduced :(

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko I'm afraid that for this problem there exists no single answer that covers all possible causes. So try one of the other answers :)